# How to show popup on AMP page after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ampscript

I'm trying to make the popup appear on the AMP page after a certain amount of time has elapsed, but getting the error in the console — `[amp-script] Blocked 1 attempts to modify DOM element attributes or styles. For variable-sized <amp-script> containers, a user action has to happen first.`. But I need to show popup without any actions on the page from user.
Any Ideas of how can I do this?

```
  <style amp-custom>
    .ampPopup {
      display: none;
    }

    .ampPopup.open {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  
  <amp-script layout='container' script='time-script' className='sample'>
    <section className='ampPopup'>
      <h1>Popup</h1>
    </section>

    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </amp-script>

  <script id='time-script' type='text/plain' target='amp-script'>
    const el = document.querySelector('.ampPopup');
    const elClose = document.querySelector('.ampPopupClose');

    setTimeout(() => {
      el.classList.add('open');

      elClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
        el.classList.remove('open');
      });
    }, 3000);
  </script>
```

I am using amp-script here, but maybe it's not the optimal way.

Comment: You can't change the DOM if a.) the amp-script doesn't have a fixed size and b.) your DOM change doesn't follow a user interaction. See [the documentation for details](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#user-gestures).

Comment: I know, and I am trying to find another way to do this. Maybe amp-animation and amp-position-observer can solve this but I can't make a work demo

Comment: The spec is written *specifically* to avoid changes to the visible content that aren't triggered by user interactions. I'm pretty sure what you want to do goes directly counter to what AMP tries to enforce and I'd guess that even if you find a way to do what you want, it would not be looked kindly upon by those who ask you to follow  the AMP spec.

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution that solve that do the trick — [sandbox](https://playground.amp.dev/#share=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)

That solution is using `amp-user-notification`

[image]

Comment: `amp-user-notification` works once, it wouldn't do that twice at the same browser.